# How to use Butterknife in Combination with a navigation header?

Tags: android, butterknife, navigationview

I bind some Views with Butterknife but it doesn't work somehow. 
The Exception i got is

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'full_name_nav'`

which basically says that he can't find the view. So i think i am binding at the wrong position, but i don't know where i should do it correctly. I am including the Navigation Header Layout in the NavigationView and binding these views in my oncreate method.

My Code:

XML Layout of the Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" <!-- Including the Navigation Header here-->
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

XML Layout of the Navigation Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/full_name_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/motorcycle_model_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Main Activity where i actually bind the views:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@BindView(R.id.full_name_nav)
TextView navigationName;

@BindView(R.id.motorcycle_model_nav)
TextView navigaitonMotorcycle;

@BindView(R.id.user_name_nav)
TextView navigationUsername;


SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ButterKnife.bind(this); // Calling ButterKnife here


    setNavInfo();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    }

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
       }
    };

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the Viewbinding in the OnCreateOptionsMenu, now it works.